# FullCalendar dayRender is showing the next days date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) for a doctor / patient appointment system. I want to show doctor availability in patient screen using FullCalendar. I am using the `dayRender` function, but is it showing me the next days date, specifically for EST time zone.  Can anyone let me know what I am missing over here?

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
            var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
            var strDay = moment(date._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/client/profile/ajaxexpertappointentclientday',
                    data: 'strDate='+strDay ,
                    type: "POST",
                    async:false,
                    success: function(intFlag) {
                        var today = moment();
                        if(intFlag == 1 && strDay >= strTodaysDate && strDay < moment(today._d).add('days', 2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
                            cell.css("background-color", "red");
                        } else {
                            cell.css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: Could you add to your question a link for the calendar library? It'll useful for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what of many fullCalendar you use.
I've used this http://fullcalendar.io/

Code example javascript

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            timeFormat: {
                agenda: 'H(:mm){ - H(:mm)}',
                '': 'H(:mm){-H(:mm) }'
            },
            aspectRatio: 2,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: false,
            theme: false,
            eventColor: '#bcdeee',
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: '/index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:
                    {
                        controller  : "engineers",
                        action      : "getCalendar"
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                    }
                }
            ],
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            },
            eventClick: function(event)
            {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open("?controller=audits&action=show&id="+event.id, '_blank').focus();
                return false;
            },
        });
```

And the response from server must be like this:

```
    [{"id":61,"title":"BOLOGNA (Bologna)","start":"2015-08-30 15:00:00+01:00","end":"2015-08-31 15:00:00+01:00","allDay":false,"color":null}]
```

if color attribute is setted on response JSON, will be the color of specific event.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/

> You can use any of the CSS color formats such #f00, #ff0000,
>   rgb(255,0,0), or red.

Comment: I got the answer, instead of using  moment(date._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), better convert it into UTC date like i have done
moment.utc(date._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: ajay, converting it to utc like that worked for me too, thanks!